# Getting extra results in content search result with Azure Search

Tags: azure-search

Using Azure search in Sitecore 9.1.1. We are getting extra results in Azure search only, with Solr results are showing correctly.

Scenario:

Fetching result from the below structure :

[image]

When we try to fetch result by passing `1999` in Azure search then it shows result for `Data 1999` folder as well.
If we pass `1998` then result shows for `1998` only, it also works when we pass `Data 1999`. Issue is with `1999` only, getting these results while passing `1999` in Azure search:

```
Test 1
Test 2
Test 3
```

Instead of

```
Test 1
Test 2
```

Using code :

`predicate = predicate.And(x => x.Year.Equals(Year));`

Comment: Could you provide the code that you are using for the request? 

looks like you are using Contains function. In that case, it will be no difference for Search Engine between `Data 1999` and `1999` folders

Comment: Also, Sitecore Query Mapper for Azure Search is very poor and has many limitations. Especially for string it all times using Contains. Also in a case when you using Equals function. 

Provide more information and then I can answer on your question

Comment: I have updated my question and using Equals operator for this.

Comment: How is your configuration defined for the year field? If you are trying to search by year on those items isn't it better to have a date field on each of them?

Comment: @SitecoreMember please flag my answer as an answer to your question if helps. Because I see a lot of similar questions but without approved answers. Probably, in that case, will be fewer duplicates in the future

Comment: for year using ```<field type="System.String"     fieldName="year"                  boost="1f" searchable="YES" retrievable="YES" facetable="YES" filterable="YES" sortable="YES" settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure.CloudSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure"/>```

Comment: I would try to change those folders to be years not string like 'Data 1999' or have a year field directly on the Test item template. Otherwise you need a computed field created as Vadim wrote

Comment: Agreed with @CristiVulturar. It can be changed to another structure if possible and there will be changed to another format by Sitecore instruments.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had a bit same case in my project. When I investigated how **Azure Search** works underhood I found that string types all times converted to `Contains` query in **Azure Search**. You can see that if taking a look into **Search.log** for your environment.

The same issue with the `StartsWith()` function and etc. [check this link](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/platform-administration-and-architecture/en/sitecore-azure-search-overview.html):

In your case I see some scenarios to resolving this issue:

1. Make a computed field/change type of field `year` on any numeric type. That can be `int`. (Equals for numeric types works well)
2. Switch to **Solr** (it will take 1-day max but will save a lot of time with Search work). Anyway, the azure search will be deprecated in the next version of Sitecore. Check [this link](https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore%20Experience%20Platform/100/Sitecore%20Experience%20Platform%20100/Release%20Notes).
3. Use straight requests to Azure Search instead of Sitecore LINQ provider. There exists an Equals function that can be used. (take a lot of time for rewriting and hard to support solution like this)
4. Take a look at the `Wildcard()` LINQ function that allows using Search Engine syntaxis for field requests. Probably it will help too.

My experience with **Azure Search** was a nightmare till we didn't switch to **Solr Engine** in all environments and removed Azure-related things from a project (before we had Azure Search for production and Solr for development). Because they're a lot of limitations.